# Why woocommerce shows only five products in category page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm new to wordpress. I've instaled woocommerce plugin in wordpress 3.9.1. And installed the add-on https://github.com/dgrundel/woo-product-importer to import the products. I imported a csv file with 15 products. All those products are belongs to one category. But when I see the frontend that category page, it shows only 5 products. Rest of the products are missing. How can I fix this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has an easy (I think) solution to this problem if you're still looking for one. Just set-up a page for each of your products and use this shortcode:

[product_category category="appliances"]

Replace appliances with whatever your category name is. It shows all your products of that category and gets you out of the WooCommerce loop so you can add more styling and content to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking *Settings > Reading* and see what it shows under *"Blog pages show at most:"* thats setting dictates how posts get shown on a page before pagination. That setting *also* affects how many products WooCommerce displays.